# match everything but a given string and do not match single characters from that string

Tags: regex

Let's start with the following input.

```
Input = 'blue, blueblue, b l u e'
```

I want to match everything that is not the string 'blue'. Note that blueblue should not match, but single characters should (even if present in match string).
From this, If I replace the matches with an empty string, it should return:

```
Result = 'blueblueblue'
```

I have tried with `[^\bblue\b]+`
but this matches the last four single characters 'b', 'l','u','e'

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: Javascript, but I am using some third party API with the following function
```Replace(on='[^\bblue\b]+', with_=u'', global_=True, ignore_case=True)```
The regex is PCRE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution:

```py
(?<=blue)(?:(?!blue).)+(?=blue|$)|^(?:(?!blue).)+(?=blue|$)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hHYbTg/1)

Comment: How would this work if instead of a word ('blue') in the example I have a string like 'bleu red'?

Comment: @Clem Do you mean something like this? https://regex101.com/r/iKdT7Q/1

Answer (score 1):

If you regex engine support the `\K` flag, then we can try:

```
/blue\K|.*?(?=blue|$)/gm
```

### Demo

This pattern says to match:

- `blue` match "blue"
- `\K` but then forget that match
- `|` OR
- `.*?` match anything else until reaching
- `(?=blue|$)` the next "blue" or the end of the string

**Edit:**

On JavaScript, we can try the following replacement:

```js
var input = "blue, blueblue, b l u e";
var output = input.replace(/blue|.*?(?=blue|$)/g, (x) => x != "blue" ? "" : "blue");
console.log(output);
```

Comment: would this work if instead of a word ('blue') in the example I have a string like ```'bleu red'```?

Comment: @Clem No, the pattern would have to change (applies to both answers given here).